# using CodeDom to generate an enum with Value as well as Name

Tags: c#, reflection, enums, codedom

I have this little piece of code :

```
    private Dictionary<string, IList<KeyValuePair<int, string>>> EnumsCollection = new Dictionary<string, IList<KeyValuePair<int, string>>>();

    // ...... Dictionary is filled, fine

    // ... outer loop
    foreach (var enumNameAndValue in EnumsCollection[enumName])
    {
         var codeProperty = new CodeMemberField
         {
              Name = enumNameAndValue.Value
         };

         codeClass.Members.Add(codeProperty);
    }
    // ...
```

Good, I get an enum :
    public enum eShape
    {
        Round,
        Square,
    }

but would it be possible to also set a Value moreover the Name?
As in :

```
public enum eShape
{
    Round = 4,
    Square = 5,
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd use [InitExpression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.codedom.codememberfield.initexpression.aspx):

```
foreach (var enumNameAndValue in EnumsCollection[enumName])
{
     var codeProperty = new CodeMemberField
     {
          Name = enumNameAndValue.Value,
          InitExpression = new CodePrimitiveExpression(enumNameAndValue.Key); // Uses key for value
     };
```

Comment: Thank you! That's all I wanted to know :p I learn something new everyday